# How to Make LinkedIn API work with PHP from scratch

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

this is my first time to work with API's in PHP, so please bear with me for asking a very basic question. All I need is to read my LinkedIn Summary from my LinkedIn profile and automatically show it on my website.

However the documentation on https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools is quite overwhelming for me, and I don't know where to start. I was pointed to http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth and I even found http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/downloads/detail?name=3.2.0.zip&can=2&q= but I just can't put all these together.

The other materials I saw online assume that I know how to install oAuth on my server. Even the LinkedIn guide assumes that too.

Could anybody give me some steps to follow to at least be able to make a call to display just the Summary from my LinkedIn profile, or maybe point me to a link that explains it for newbies? My website is hosted free on x10hosting.com.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a quick start guide (which has PHP code) here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

It does, however, require that you know how to install libraries on your server.  This is a requirement for any OAuth library.

Comment: i see... alright.. i haave to go that way, then. i decided not to do it for now, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Kirsten Jones Despite the question being so old, I thought I might still ask you if there is any way of using LinkedIn API as an equivalent to Google's "service account", that is, authorizing your request and then make calls against the API in behalf of the service account (no particular user). This assumes no sign in thingy in my app (although I may need it later). At the moment I need to get/fetch/scrape public information off of any LinkedIn profile based on user's ID. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to setup PECL Package in your server than you can go with oAuth and you can use LinkedIn rest API with it https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-api-resource-map

Now to call this API you can download this simple linkedin library https://github.com/mahmudahsan/Linkedin---Simple-integration-for-your-website. there is also demo given with it.

First you need to create Linkedin Application from here https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer?newapp=  to get linkedin_access and linkedin_secret.

So when you have your linkedin_access and linkedin_secret just go to the demo.php of the library you have download and put there.

Now you can call the REST API and get thr result.